# How to get full referrer in Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

Several days ago, I just following the instructions at

http://www.slideshare.net/pandyajigar/how-to-see-the-full-referring-url-in-google-analytics-by-jigar-pandya

to add a filter in order to get the full referrer path in Google analytics report.

Now I still cannot figure out how to see the full referrer, I go to "Standard Report", then "Conversions", then "Ecommerce", then "Transactions", I can see the transaction report, then in "Secondardy dimension: Referral Path", I can see the referrer path but it is still relative, like this:

```
/question/78
```

I cannot find a way to see the full referrer yet.

Comment: Note that this method for accessing the full referrer is not available in GA4, which is now default as of 2021. You may still use it with Universal Analytics properties, which you can create if you go to "Advanced" during the property creation process.

Answer (score 10):

You need to select Secondary Dimension > Behavior > Full Referrer or select the alphabetical listing and navigate straight to it. That will provide a report column with the full referrer URLs. You can make this more convenient by constructing a custom report if you need to access this data frequently.

Comment: This data doesn't seem available anymore. Google's just giving me the referring domain as the "full referrer", even though that's impossible. e.g. it'll show "domain.com/", even though domain.com doesn't host any links on its homepage.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure the `referral path` and `source` are always separated in google analytics, so getting a single field with the full URL is not something you will find (at least without doing some additional work). The fact that you are now getting the *full referral path* (Which is what I think you are saying) means you could make a custom report with the following settings:

> **Type:** `Flat Table`
>
> **Dimensions:** `Source`, `Referral Path`
>
> **Metric:** `Visits`

Then export to csv and merge these two columns in excel / other spreadsheet software.

This is if I correctly understand your request...

Answer (score -1):

OK, you're going to need some excel to do this.

So:
Standard Report -> E-commerce -> Transactions and set the secondary dimension to referral path.
Export this to excel and go to tab Dataset 1

Now create a report using:
Standard Report -> E-commerce -> Transactions and set the secondary dimension to Source
Export this to excel and go to tab Dataset 1

Now do go back to the first Dataset and do a VLOOKUP on column A:

To do this type

```
=VLOOKUP(

now click column A item 2

add a ,

Then go to the second sheet and select columns A and B in full

add a ,2 and close the function
```

You'll get something like

```
=vlookup(a2,$A:$B,2)
```

What this does is give you the value matching the ID from both columns

Now you can concatenate them together to get the full url:

```
=CONCATENATE(G2,A2)
```